# Seeing all regex matches in a file in Bash

Tags: bash, files, regular-expression

I'm in bash and I have a file, I want to find all matches of a regex in it and have them printed. How do I do that?

Followup: Assume I want to print only unique matches, i.e. if a match appears multiple times, it should be printed only once. How do I do that? (I want this answer in addition to the first, so I want an answer to the first question too.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `grep -o 'myregex.*stuff' file` and for the second question `grep -o 'myregex.*stuff' file | sort | uniq`.

The `-o` grep switch will print only the matches instead of printing the whole line that matches the regex.

Comment: just a side note, you can use `sort -u` instead piping to `uniq`

Comment: `uniq` isn't right, it only handles successive repetitions. Fixed answer. Thank you!

Comment: I tend to use `sort | uniq` in combination instead of `sort -u` because I might want to extend it to `sort | uniq -c | sort -n`. Also `uniq` will be right if you have the output sorted before, like suggested.